# SQL JOIN AND NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
comms                       
+-------------+
|    uuid     |
+-------------+
| comm_uuid_1 |
| comm_uuid_2 |
+-------------+

events

+--------------+-------------+
|     uuid     |  comm_uuid  |
+--------------+-------------+
| event_uuid_1 | comm_uuid_1 |
| event_uuid_2 | comm_uuid_1 |
+--------------+-------------+

actions
+---------------+-------+---------------------+
|     uuid      | type  |     event_uuid      |
+---------------+-------+---------------------+
| random_uuid_1 | stack | event_uuid_1        |
| random_uuid_2 | pop   | event_uuid_1        |
+---------------+-------+---------------------+
```

Basically I'm trying to get all the comms that their events match certain criteria, but the filters are in the actions from the events, this is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT * 
FROM comms JOIN events ON events.comm_uuid = comms.uuid 
AND (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM actions
WHERE events.uuid = actions.event_uuid AND actions.type = 'stack')) 
AND (not EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM actions
WHERE events.uuid = actions.event_uuid AND actions.type = 'pop'))
```

In this case that query should return nothing because there are events with actions.type = stack but there are also events in the same comm with actions.type = pop, for some reason this is returning me the communication related with action.type = stack, I only want that if there are no action.type = pop in the events from the same comm.

Comment: Now this query return empty result, so it  looks like there is error in data in actions table - second row should have 'event_uuid_2'.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT * FROM comms 
WHERE 
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM actions
       JOIN events on (events.uuid = actions.event_uuid)
          WHERE events.comm_uuid = comms.uuid 
            AND actions.type = 'stack') 
  AND NOT EXISTS ( 
    SELECT 1 FROM actions
     JOIN events on (events.uuid = actions.event_uuid)
       WHERE events.comm_uuid = comms.uuid 
        AND actions.type = 'pop'
  )
```